# Using unicode for a custom android keyboard

Tags: android, xml, unicode, keyboard, keycode

I am creating a Bhutanese keyboard for an android App.  I am using unicode.  However, I am getting error messages when I try to run the app that say "error parsing keycode", and the letters do not show up when they are pressed.

Here is a sample of the keyboard xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="0px"
    android:keyHeight="60dp">
     <Row>
        <Key android:codes="U+0F09" android:keyLabel="༉" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="U+0F21" android:keyLabel="༡"/>
        <Key android:codes="U+0F22" android:keyLabel="༢"/>
        <Key android:codes="U+0F23" android:keyLabel="༣"/>
        <Key android:codes="U+0F24" android:keyLabel="༤"/>
        <Key android:codes="U+0F25" android:keyLabel="༥"/>
        <Key android:codes="U+0F26" android:keyLabel="༦"/>
        <Key android:codes="U+0F27" android:keyLabel="༧"/>
        <Key android:codes="U+0F28" android:keyLabel="༨"/>
        <Key android:codes="U+0F29" android:keyLabel="༩"/>
        <Key android:codes="U+0F20" android:keyLabel="༠"/>
        <Key android:codes="U+0F14" android:keyLabel="༔"/>
        <Key android:codes="U+0F0D" android:keyLabel="།"/>
        <Key android:codes="U+0F5D" android:keyLabel="ཝ" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
```

My keyboard workded when it was an english keyboard, like this one:

```
 <Key android:codes="113" android:keyLabel="q" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="119" android:keyLabel="w"/>
    <Key android:codes="101" android:keyLabel="e"/>
    <Key android:codes="114" android:keyLabel="r"/>
    <Key android:codes="116" android:keyLabel="t"/>
    <Key android:codes="121" android:keyLabel="y"/>
    <Key android:codes="117" android:keyLabel="u"/>
    <Key android:codes="105" android:keyLabel="i"/>
    <Key android:codes="111" android:keyLabel="o"/>
    <Key android:codes="112" android:keyLabel="p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
</Row>
```

Am I not supposed to use unicode for a custom android keyboard?  Or if I can, what can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

To fix the parse error you can either:

1. replace "U+0F09" with the decimal (3849) value of the Unicode.
2. leave the android code out. The code should be auto generated based
   on the character in keyLabel. I've tested this with English and
   Spanish characters.

Answer (score 0):

to fix the parse error:

- replace `"U+0F09"` with the `0x...` format to be like that `"0xF09"`

You can use this site for conversion:
https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/